# React Button element id giving empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I want to pass the id of my Button in my function call when the button is clicked. But How to do that? I read the available solutions but nothing helped me.

**Problem:** The below code prints an empty string in the console

**Expectation:** paras123 should get printed

```
<TableCell align="center">
   <Button id="paras123" onClick={(e)=>console.log(e.target.id)}>
      Pre-Session Form
   </Button>
 </TableCell>
```

Comment: Can you share Button component code or is it being used from a framework?

Answer (score 2):

Because `target` is the span show text `Pre-Session Form`. You need use currentTarget to get button id:

```
onClick={(e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `target` value : `console.log(e.target)`. It will response following like that

```
<span class="MuiButton-label">Pre-Session Form</span>
```

There is no `id` value. If your idea is to print `paras123`, check this example link.

`https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-paper-ftumv?file=/src/App.js:1592-1595`